# How to convert const unsigned char* payLoad to char* and copy it?

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof, memcpy, const-char

I'm trying to convert a `const unsigned char*` to `char*` as well as make a copy. I have tried several variations of the code below but I usually get a memory exception. This function resides in an application written in C.

The below function is what I'm trying to create

```
//global variable
char* copiedValue;

void convertUnsignedChar(const unsigned char* message){

    copiedValue = malloc(sizeof(message));
    (void)memcpy(copiedValue, message, sizeof(message));

}
```

Comment: *Why* do you need to "convert" the data? Do you need to modify it? While not in standard C (but in other standards) you probably have a `strdup` function which possibly might do what you want (if the contents is a string). Oh and don't forget to `free` the data sometime, or you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the pointer? If you have to remove the `const` qualifier, your system design is most probably broken, as it is not `const`-correct.

Answer (score 1):

A large part of your problem is `sizeof(message)` which gives you the size of *the pointer*, not what it points to.

Either pass the length to the function, or (if the data is a null-terminated string) use [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) to get the length (but don't forget to add one for the terminator!) or the above mentioned `strdup` function (if available).

Answer (score 1):

`malloc(sizeof(message))` only allocates space for a `char *` pointer, probably 8 bytes. You need to allocate space for the data which `message` points to.

There's a bit of a problem: how much data is pointed at by `message`? Is it null terminated? Let's assume it is, then you can use `strlen`. Don't forget space for the null byte!

```
copiedValue = malloc(strlen((char*)message) + 1);
```

Similarly for `memcpy`.

```
memcpy(copiedValue, message, strlen((char*)message) + 1);
```

Note, there's no need to cast `memcpy`'s return value to `void`.

---

Or use the POSIX `strdup` function.

```
copiedValue = strdup((char *)message);
```

Comment: @M.M Thanks, fixed that.